# confused between class attributes and instance attributes

Tags: python, django

Suppose i have this django model

```
class Article(object):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=320)
       body  = models.CharField(max_length=320)
       def __init__(self):
              setattr(Article,"user",get_logged_username())
```

That was just the sample code

I just want to know that as i am setting the class attribute not instance attribute so will my every user have the same `user` attribute

like initially it is `john` then some othe rperson his browser and click on add new article

then if i check my `user` then it will be same his username or not

Comment: You said yourself 'every user have the same `user` attribute'. Obviously the attribute isn't going to vary over users.

Comment: Note that `setattr(Article, "user", …)` is more simply directly written `Article.user = …`.

Comment: Are you sure you really want that **every article in the database** should have the same user?

Comment: I believe `CharField` is actually a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors), so there are more complex things going on than a simply assignment when you set `title` and `body` attributes on the instance.

Comment: @Bakuriu can you please elaborate in detail what u want to say. that looks interesting to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care that each creation of a new instance will put the class attribute `user` at the same value:

```
class Article(object):
       title = '111'
       body  = '222'
       def __init__(self):
              setattr(Article,"user",145)

aaaaaaa = Article()
print '# aaaaaaa = Article()  /done'
print '  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == %r ' % aaaaaaa.__dict__
print '  aaaaaaa.user == %r ' % aaaaaaa.user
print '  Article.user == %r\n' % Article.user

aaaaaaa.user = 2000
print '# aaaaaaa.user = 2000  /done'
print '  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == %r ' % aaaaaaa.__dict__
print '  aaaaaaa.user == %r ' % aaaaaaa.user
print '  Article.user == %r\n' % Article.user

Article.user = 'JUJU'
print "# Article.user = 'JUJU'  /done"
print '  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == %r ' % aaaaaaa.__dict__
print '  aaaaaaa.user == %r ' % aaaaaaa.user
print '  Article.user == %r\n' % Article.user

bbbbbbb = Article()
print '# bbbbbbb = Article()  /done'
print '  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == %r ' % aaaaaaa.__dict__
print '  aaaaaaa.user == %r ' % aaaaaaa.user
print '    bbbbbbb.__dict__ == %r ' % bbbbbbb.__dict__
print '    bbbbbbb.user == %r ' % bbbbbbb.user
print '    Article.user == %r ' % Article.user
```

result

```
# aaaaaaa = Article()  /done
  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == {} 
  aaaaaaa.user == 145 
  Article.user == 145

# aaaaaaa.user = 2000  /done
  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == {'user': 2000} 
  aaaaaaa.user == 2000 
  Article.user == 145

# Article.user = 'JUJU'  /done
  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == {'user': 2000} 
  aaaaaaa.user == 2000 
  Article.user == 'JUJU'

# bbbbbbb = Article()  /done
  aaaaaaa.__dict__ == {'user': 2000} 
  aaaaaaa.user == 2000 
    bbbbbbb.__dict__ == {} 
    bbbbbbb.user == 145 
    Article.user == 145
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a *class* attribute, here, since `Article` is a class.

This means that all your instances will share this attribute:

```
>>> class Article(object):
...     def __init__(self, user):
...         Article.user = user
...         

>>> article_john = Article('John')
>>> article_elli = Article('Ellie')                                                 

>>> article_john.user  # Modified by the second Article creation!
'Ellie'
```

Note, however, that the objects (instances) can have their own `user` attribute, which overrides the class attribute:

```
>>> article_john.user = 'This was initially John'
>>> article_ellie.user  # Unmodified, because it access the class attribute Article.user
'Ellie'
```

Per-instance attributes are simply set with `self.user = get_logged_username()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set the *instance attribute*, not the class attribute.

```
setattr(self,"user",get_logged_username())
```

Or...

```
this.user = get_logged_username()
```

If you want all instances of the class to initially have a `name` attribute of `john`, just make when when you declare the class.

```
class Article:
    name = 'john'
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting class attributes, you may want to limit yourself to objects that will be shared across many or all instances of that class. For values that will change or be unique to each instance, set them in the **init**() method.

For example, you may have a threading.Lock instance that is used when creating an instance, and then a per-instance threading.Lock that will be engaged for per-instance synchronization tasks.

```
class Article:
    creation = threading.Lock
    count = 0

    def __init__ (self):
        Article.creation.acquire ()

        self.id = Article.count
        self.lock = threading.Lock

        Article.count += 1
        Article.creation.release ()


    def critical (self):
        self.lock.acquire ()

        # Something sensitive happens here.

        self.lock.release ()
```

To go back to your original question, you likely want:

```
class Article(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.title = models.CharField(max_length=320)
       self.body  = models.CharField(max_length=320)
       self.user  = get_logged_username()
```